# Rails console - process finished with exit code 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

Can't start rails console. When I'm trying to start it I 've got this message:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It exits without any errors. But rails server starts without problems:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-04-26 02:23:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-26 02:23:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
[2013-04-26 02:23:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2393 port=3000
```

I'm running Mac OS X with rvm.
Why rails console may not be working?

Comment: What happens when you run `ruby script/rails console` instead of `rails console`?

Comment: Nothing
    `bash-3.2$ ruby script/rails console`
    `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)`
    `bash-3.2$`

Comment: What happens if you run `irb` from the terminal? Also, does rails console run on new rails apps? Try running `rails new some_app` and then run `rails c`.

Comment: `irb` runs ok. `rails new` creates new app without any problem, but got the same problem with `rails c` for the just created app. I think that something wrong with rvm. Trying running `rails c` with debug.

Comment: Is there any more information in the development.log file? Also, when you irb, start typing lines from your `environment.rb` file and see what happens.

Comment: @AntonGrigoryev Did you previously have upgraded your rails?

Comment: if you can, remove `/tmp` files and also `.*` folder which is on rails root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using RVM, try doing `rvm implode` and reinstall Ruby and Rails.

Comment: So this was the only solution

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with bundle exec?

```
bundle exec rails c
```

Comment: Nothing happens  
`bash-3.2$ bundle exec rails c    
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)  
   
bash-3.2$`